# Group by column values based on another column condition along with sum and count

Tags: python, pandas

I want to set my policy as a variable so that I can input whichever policy I want. Group by shows, count the number of shows appeared, sum the views and sum the revenue. How can I achieve this?

My table looks like

```
policy.    show.    views.  revenue
10 min.    batman.   100.     10
10 min     batman.   200.     20
5 min.     joker.    100.     10
5 min      joker.    300.     15
15 min.    superman. 500.     30
```

My expected output is

Policy = '10 min'

```
Show       count    total_views    total_revenue
batman.    2.        300.            30
```

If I give policy = '5 min', My output should be

```
 Show       count    total_views    total_revenue
 joker.     2.        400.            25
```

Similarly for any other policies, I give under the variable policy

Comment: Try with `groupby` with `agg`

Comment: Shouldn't your output be `joker.     2.        400.            25` ?? And your `policy.` column is un-standardized: why do some values have a period at the end and some don't.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
def set_policy(df, policy):
    filtered = df[df['policy'] == policy]
    t = {'show': filtered['show'].unique()[0], 'count': filtered.shape[0],
         'total_views': filtered['views'].sum(), 'total_revenue': filtered['revenue'].sum()}
    return pd.DataFrame([t])

df = set_policy(df, '10min')
```

Output:

```
     show  count  total_views  total_revenue
0  batman      2          300             30
```

Update

Example dataframe

```
  policy      show  views  revenue
0  10min    batman    100       10
1  10min    batman    200       20
2   5min     joker    100       10
3   5min     joker    300       15
4  15min  superman    500       30
5  10min  superman    100       20
```

The code:

```
def set_policy(df, policy):
    t = defaultdict(list)
    filtered = df[df['policy'] == policy]
    gp = filtered.groupby('show')
    for i, k in gp:
        t['show'].append(k['show'].unique()[0])
        t['count'].append(k.shape[0])
        t['total_views'].append(k['views'].sum())
        t['total_revenue'].append(k['revenue'].sum())
    return pd.DataFrame(t)

df = set_policy(df, '10min')
```

Output

```
       show  count  total_views  total_revenue
0    batman      2          300             30
1  superman      1          100             20
```

Comment: I get this error:  index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: Did you checked column names? Your have '.' at the end. And policy value contains space.

Comment: I printed my df and checked to see if i have all. the data. Its good

Comment: I'm seeing all the show titles in a single cell with collective numbers. I want all the series grouped by individual show names

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now the code able to display multiple shows.

Comment: what is t = defaultdict(list)

Comment: @Yash https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict